# Magento errors when I try to add extentions

Tags: magento

Found some errors when I try to add the extensions. I already try both methods Help me please check attached screenshot[image]

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12158/what-permissions-should-i-give-var-and-media

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can download extension directly [freezento](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)